# Quebrar uma lista e criar lista de listas

Tags: python, lista, split

olá! Tenho a seguinte lista em python de números:

```
['1','2','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
```

E eu quero quebrar essa lista e criar outras listas de tal forma que fique assim:

```
[['1','2'],
 ['1','2','3','4'],
 ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'],
 ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']]
```

Estou sem ideiais de como fazer essa operação.

O críterio de quebra é sempre que encontrar o número 1.

Comment: Adicione na pergunta como tentou abordar problema e quais foram os problemas enfrentados e mensagens de erro. Veja o [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8496/checklist-de-perguntas-do-stack-overflow)

Comment: Qual o critério para a quebra? Quando deve começar uma lista nova?

Comment: Olá! O críterio para a nova lista é sempre que encontrar o número 1. Desculpe se ficou confuso, só percebi agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você percorrer a sua sequência buscando o valor `'1'` e acumulando temporariamente em uma variável auxiliar. Sempre que encontrar o valor você *retorna* o valor da variável temporária no seu gerador.

```py
def split(sequence):
    output = []
    for value in sequence:
        if value == '1' and output:
            yield output
            output = []
        output.append(value)
    if output:
        yield output
```

Assim, para a sua entrada, poderíamos fazer:

```
lista = ['1','2','1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']

for sub_listas in split(lista):
    print(sub_listas)
```

Que a saída será:

```
['1', '2']
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```